# Centroids in K-Mean clustering

Tags: matlab, image-processing, k-means

I am trying to do k-mean clustering of a gray-scale image.

The code is as follows:

```
I = im2double(imread('sample.png'));
J = rgb2gray(I);
r = size(J,1);
c = size(J,2);
J = reshape(J,r*c,1);

[cluster_idx, cluster_center] = kmeans(J,k,'start','uniform','distance','sqEuclidean', 'Replicates', 3);
```

Here cluster_idx has the cluster indices for each row of the input image. And cluster_center has the cluster centroid locations. But this will be a k x 1 matrix. What I don't get is how these values(double) are representing the centroids for the clusters of the input image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cluster_center` represents the mean **gray level** of each cluster, while `cluster_idx` assigns each pixel with a **cluster membership**.

just `reshape` your clustering result back to the original image size, and use `cluster_idx` as the `cluster_center` indexes:

```
J = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
r = size(J,1);
c = size(J,2);
J = reshape(J,r*c,1);
k = 3;
[cluster_idx, cluster_center] = kmeans(J,k,'start','uniform','distance','sqEuclidean', 'Replicates', 3);

II = reshape(cluster_idx,[r c]);
JJ = cluster_center(II);
imshow(JJ);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes you are correct about this. But I am still not clear with how II being a completely white image(at least to me) we get JJ as the clustered image above. What does cluster_center actually represent here. I know that its supposed to be the centroids for the clusters but I am unable to imagine this as it is a one dimensional. I am very new to MATLAB .

Comment: `cluster_center` represents the mean **gray level** of each cluster, while `cluster_idx` assigns each pixel with a **cluster membership**.

Comment: Got it thanks for your time. Can you please edit your answer to add this information as it was what I was looking for.

Comment: Just wondering are these cluster_center values sorted in any way ? Meaning is it like the first cluster has the highest/lowest mean gray level and so on.

Comment: The Kmeans initialization is random so the clusters values are not necessarily sorted.

Comment: Yes seems to be the case. Figured it out using a few examples. Thanks anyways.